# C: Why am I getting 'Floating Point Exception: 8' From This Calculation?

Tags: c, exception, floating-point, integer

Here is my function:

```
int scoreString(char *toScore) {
    int length = strlen(toScore);
    int score = 0;
    int spaceCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char current = toScore[i];
        if (current == ' ') {
            spaceCount++;
        }
        score += scoreChar(current);
    }
    //English words are ~5 characters
    int charsPerWord = (length/(spaceCount + 1));
    if (charsPerWord >=3 && charsPerWord <= 7) {
        //Big Bonus
        score = score * 2; //THIS LINE CAUSES PROBLEMS
    } else if (spaceCount <= 1) {
        //Big penalty
        score = score / 2; //THIS LINE CAUSES PROBLEMS
    }
    return score;
}
```

If I get ride of the two lines that are marked as causing problems, everything is dandy.  The output of this function without them ranges from 100-2000 on the input I'm testing so this should not be an overflow error ... if I leave either of those two lines in I get `Floating point exception: 8` after a few executions.  Any ideas?

Comment: What environment is this happening in?  Platform, compiler, and C runtime library.

Comment: Is there any chance that `score` is near the limit of `int`? (2^32 in 32-bit architecture, or 2^64 in 64-bit architectures.)  Though that would only explain the multiply; the divide is always safe as an `int`.  For what value of `toScore` does it exhibit the exception?

Comment: Either by using a debugger or by adding `printf` calls, examine the value of `score` before the calculation. But I'd be surprised to see an integer overflow, or particularly a division by a non-zero value, cause a floating-point exception.

Comment: Can you put a `main` in there and give us `scoreChar`, to make this at least semi-compilable?

Comment: This is on Mac OS X 10.8 using clang for compiler.   When I comment those lines out all of the final returned `score` values are less than 4000 so the `*2` and `/2` would be putting them in the 0-8000 range.